# Can you render user message before it appears in webchat?

Tags: botframework, web-chat

For MS Botframework webchat, Is there a way to intercept user message before being rendered in webchat and change it?

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to accomplish using the `createStore()` method.

In the web chat script located in your page, create the store using the above method. In it, match the `action.type` to 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_MESSAGE'. This will capture every message that is passed thru the web chat component before it is displayed.

Be aware, this altered text (or whatever value you are changing) is what is sent to the bot. `action` is the root object. `action.payload`, effectively, represents the activity. This is where you will find the text value, etc.

Within the `if` statement, perform whatever change you are looking to make, then return the `action` object.

Lastly, include the `store` object within the `renderWebChat` component. This should set you up.

In the example below, I am appending text to the text field altering it before it is rendered and displayed.

```html
<script>
  ( async function () {
    const res = await fetch( 'http://somesite/directline/token', { method: 'POST' } );
    const { token } = await res.json();

    // We are using a customized store to add hooks to connect event
    const store = window.WebChat.createStore( {}, ( { dispatch } ) => next => action => {
      if ( action.type === 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_MESSAGE' ) {
        action.payload.text = action.payload.text + ' (Hello from behind the curtain)'
      }

      return next( action );
    } );

    window.WebChat.renderWebChat( {
      directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine( { token } ),
      userID: 'user123',
      username: 'johndoe',
      botAvatarInitials: 'BB',
      userAvatarInitials: 'JD',
      store
    }, document.getElementById( 'webchat' ) );
    document.querySelector( '#webchat > *' ).focus();

  } )().catch( err => console.error( err ) );
</script>
```

[image]

[image]

Hope of help!